# jetpack compose crash when removing item from lazy column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The current code below crashes when I swipe to delete an item from a list. I understand why the crash is occuring and it's becauase of an index out of range error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2, size 2`, but I don't know where to implment the fix so the compile knows of the change.

```
@Composable
fun ManageHelpfulCotsView(
    coreDataListViewModel: CoreDataListViewModel,
    dataStoreVM: DataStoreViewModel,
    navController: NavController,
) {
    val showDetailSheet = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val userHelpfulCotIDs =
        coreDataListViewModel.userProfileList.collectAsState(initial = listOf()).value?.filter { it.userName == coreDataListViewModel.profileName }

    val userHelpfulCots = coreDataListViewModel.barracksList.collectAsState(initial = listOf()).value?.filter {
        userHelpfulCotIDs?.firstOrNull { profile ->
            profile.helpfulCots?.contains(it.id) ?: false
        } != null
    }

    val userId = remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            runBlocking {
                dataStoreVM.hasUserProfileID()
            }
        )
    }

    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val userHelpCots = userHelpfulCots ?: emptyList() // Ensure userHelpCots is not null

        itemsIndexed(userHelpCots) { index, barracksItem ->
                if (showDetailSheet.value) {
                    HelpfulSheet(
                        dataStoreVM = dataStoreVM,
                        coreDataModel = coreDataListViewModel,
                        navController = navController,
                        isHots = false
                    ) {
                        showDetailSheet.value = false
                    }
                }
                    BarracksEntryRowView(
                        qualityHousing = barracksItem,
                        navigationAction = {
                            showDetailSheet.value = true
                        },
                        coreDataViewModel = coreDataListViewModel,
                        userId = userId.value
                    )
                }
            }
    }
```

Here's the crash stack

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.rob.hotscots, PID: 25831
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4, size 4
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.checkIndexBounds(IntervalList.kt:183)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.get(IntervalList.kt:166)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutIntervalContent.getKey(LazyLayoutIntervalContent.kt:86)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListItemProviderImpl.getKey(LazyListItemProvider.kt:85)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure(LazyListMeasuredItemProvider.kt:46)
```

Comment: Is the crash in the composable or in the ViewModel or other layers? Share the stack trace.

Comment: @Abhimanyu i've added a portion of the crash stack, let me know if you need more.

Comment: Can you check your compose version and see if this issue is similar to yours? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/306301019. If not, kindly add the compose version you are using and share a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the crash by updating some of the `vals`

`val hotsList = coreDataListViewModel.dfacList.collectAsState(initial = listOf()).value`

here as well

`if (userHelpfulHotIDs.isNullOrEmpty() || userHelpfulHotIDs.firstOrNull()?.helpfulHots.isNullOrEmpty()) { EmptyView("No Helpful content found. Return here to see posts you've found helpful.") }`

I also performed a check

`if (userHelpfulHotIDs?.first()?.helpfulHots?.contains(dfacItem.id) == true) {`